# How to create this floating layers' effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, 3d, layer-style, ipad

So I need to create a floating layer effect (as the one shown on picture) over the display of a stock iPad image.
Any suggestions, except simply applying an outer shadow effect and playing with the free transform tool?

[image]

Comment: HI Dimitar, welcome to GD.SE. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or join us in chat once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make new layers with each of these images on them (except Background of course)
2. Select all of these image layers
3. Edit -> Transform -> Distort
4. Enter these values: 
   W: 80%
   H: 45%
   Angle: 5,86
   H: -30
   V: 0,00
5. Press Enter
6. Double-click on layer
7. Click on "Drop Shadow"
8. Make a nice Drop Shadow, like in the image, it is not too hard -> Enter
9. Right-click on the layer, where the Drop Shadow is
10. Click "Copy Layer Style"
11. Select the other layers that you want to have the drop shadows on
12. Right click -> Paste Layer Style
13. Adjust layers